# Spring can't load xml configuration file

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

This error blows my brain. All the junit tests is fine but when my application loads as plugin for another application I have an errors. The beans.xml is 100% at root of jar file but for some reason the main application, that loads my plugin can't find the file. Why?

In my application's boot method I call
`new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");` throws

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

or

`new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("beans.xml").getPath());` throws

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from URL [file:/C:/path/to/my.jar!/beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\path\to\my.jar!\beans.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)`

---

**UPD:** The problem was the application uses custom classloader that does not load resource files in root, META-INF and etc. but only classes

Comment: What do you mean by 'root of jar file', can you check in what path it is located?

Comment: @Jama I mean that beans.xml located in jar file as it must be.

Answer (score 1):

The FileNotFoundException that you get really points out that the beans.xml file is not in your jar at the place where you think it is. I would have a look inside that jar. You can for example open the jar [with the 7-zip tool](http://www.7-zip.org/). I find that this provides useful insight when you get errors like the one you report.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the `FileNotFoundException` it is because the file is not located where you're looking for it. The `beans.xml` file must be located in `src/main/resources`